# AWS Glue crawler - partition keys types

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am using Spark to write files to S3 in ORC format.
Also using Athena to query this data.

I am using the following partition keys:

```
s3://bucket/company=1123/date=20190207
```

Once I execute the Glue crawler to run on the bucket everything works as expected except the types of the partitions keys.

The Crawler configures them in the catalog as `String` type instead of `int`

Is there a configuration to define the default type of the partition keys ?

I know it can be changed manually later and set the Crawler config to `Add new columns only.`

Comment: Have you found solution so far? Get stuck with the same problem: all my partition keys are of type int, but crawler discovers them as strings...

Comment: After the first run of the crawler I set the keys to integer type and change the Crawler config to `Add new columns only`

Comment: It makes sense, but I was hoping that there's some configurable / programmatic option from the beginning to handle partition types discovery. This manual adjustment doesn't fit well into provisioning automation. Also `Add new columns only` option doesn't work well, when the schema is subjected to change once in a while, as it's so easy to forget this particular crawler config value...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Glue crawlers always treat partition keys as type string and unfortunately there is no configuration option available to change this behavior.

Comment: is this still true.  I'm seeing crawler recast a partition column "year" which is an integer column as type string.  Can't seem to change it.

Comment: @SidharthRamesh Which configuration will change the partition's datatype from string to int?