# How to tell AWS Crawler to parse a partition as a date?

Tags: terraform, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a S3 folder with parquet data that I want to access from Athena tables. The folder structure is:

```
s3://my-bucket/my-table/dt=2023-04-19/my-files-XXX.parquet
```

The problem is that the crawler understands `dt` as a string and I want it to be detected as a `date`.

How can I specify the type of the partitions to the Crawler?

Comment: Seems that’s the default behaviour and cannot be changed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54574987/aws-glue-crawler-partition-keys-types?rq=2

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom classifiers on Glue. Please refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#custom-classifier-grok for further details. You can easily create in on the Glue console. For your task, I assume GROK pattern would be :

```
dt=%{YEAR:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day}
```

Comment: I guess that this still reads the ISO8601 as a string no? Where do you cast to a date?